# building a chrome extension in typescript with vue-cli for the background.js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli

I'm working on a chrome extension building off a `vue-cli` project.

My project's structure is:

```
- dist/
-       /background.js
- public/
-       /background.js <-- how would i make this .ts
- src/
-    /main.ts
-    /App.vue
```

In order to get a `background.js` file in my root directory, I need to place it in `public`.

But the only place `vue-cli` by default builds typescript (via webpack) is if it's in the `src` directory.

How can I create my `background.ts` (typescript) file so that it builds into the `public` directory, while maintaining the structure of my web app's files in the `src` directory?

Here's the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "chrome"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can config the [outputDir](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir) in `vue-cli`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I still want the output to go to `dist` (which is the default value). I can't figure out how to change the output for a single file (`background.ts`) to go to `dist` while the rest of the app continues to build as usual

Answer (score 0):

As of final version of Vue CLI 5.0 we can use Webpack chaining in a custom vue config file to overide the webpack config.

We need to declare a new entry, `./src/background.ts` and a conditional output. No need to move it into public as it will be output to the root of `dist` by default.

```js
// ./vue-cli-project/vue.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .entry('background')
      .add('./src/background.ts')
      .end()
      .output.filename((pathData) => {
        switch (pathData.chunk.name) {
          case 'background':
            return '[name].js';
          default:
            return 'js/[name].js';
        }
      })
      .end();
  }
});
```

Files

```
vue-cli-project/
├─ dist/ <-- output from webpack
│  ├─ background.js 
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ js/
|  |  ├─ index.js
├─ public/
│  ├─ index.html
├─ src/
│  ├─ background.ts
|  ├─ main.ts
|  ├─ App.vue 
├─ vue.config.js
```

#### Sources

- Vue CLI: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced
- Webpack Chain: https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain